# Linear Transformation with different bases

Tags: linear-algebra

In this exercise: Let $V$ be the subspace of $R[x]$ spanned by $1, x, x^2, x^3$, let $W:=\mathbb{R}^3$ and let $f: V\to W$ be defined by $f(p) := (p(1), p(2), p(3))$

I have to determine the matrix corresponding to $f$ with respect to the bases: $1, x, x^2, x^3$ for $V$ and $e_1, e_2, e_3$ for $W$.

So far I applied the rules given but I'm not completly sure that my solution $$\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
 2 & 2 & 4 & 8\\
 3 & 3 & 9 & 27
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thanks alot, been looking for it

Comment: I believe the solution is: $$\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
 1 & 2 & 4 & 8\\
 1 & 3 & 9 & 27
\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

the first column is not correct. think about what happens if $p = 1$.
what are $p(1)$, $p(2)$, $p(3)$?

Comment: I can see it now, would just be ones, thank you!